# Way to manipulate Z3 data structures?

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to take mathematical functions as input and algorithmically change the values before checking with z3 if the new manipulated formulas are satisfiable. I am hoping there is some tree structure I can use. I do not want to make my own because I would like to use an existing parser to convert the formulas to z3 format. Is there such a thing? Or can I manipulate SMT 2.0 formulas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking a different question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430279/z3-check-python-string-satisfiability? You really need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes sorry, If I ask for the input to be well-formatted SMTLib scripts and use z3's built in parser to parse them, how do I manipulate the data structure they are stored in? For example if I want to manipulate Implies(Or(p, p), p) to become Or(p, p) == p, And(p,p) == p etc. and I need the manipulated formulas to also be in z3 format. @alias Thank you for your response

Comment: As Christoph answered, your best bet is to directly use the API, which isn't difficult but has quite a bit of a learning curve. I assume you want to do this in Python. Start by studying the API: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html

Comment: Thank you @alias . I've been reading the API but I still don't understand what I can use to represent an expression in a tree-like data structure. Are there more concrete examples? Because from the link I can see the classes but I can't figure out how to use them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Z3's ASTs via it's API. The SMT2 format is relatively simple though,  so writing your own parser and/or serialiser isn't that hard (it's very close to Lisp).

Comment: Is there no existing parser that parses an SMT2 string to a tree data structure in python?

Comment: I've written my own before, but not published it. If you want to keep it solver-agnostic, you could look into https://github.com/pysmt/pysmt .